# Kotlin data class with derived properties

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a class that is the summary of 2 classes. I made this class a data class, as follows

```
data class Device(private val deviceModel: DeviceModel, private val deviceStatus: DeviceStatusModel) {
    val name = deviceModel.name ?: "Unknown"
    val id = deviceModel.id ?: -1
    val mode = when(deviceStatus.mode) {
        1 -> DEVICE_MODE_MANUAL
        2 -> DEVICE_MODE_AUTO
        3 -> DEVICE_MODE_OVERRIDE
        else -> DEVICE_MODE_MANUAL
    }
    val strength = deviceStatus.strength ?: 0
}
```

However when I print this class it does not print the name, id, mode and strength properties, it prints the device model and device status. Is there a way to have the class generate the toString based on the derived properties as opposed to the constructor ones?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DeviceModel and DeviceStatusModel are used for the toString() because you declared them as properties through the primary constructor to do what you want you must use a secondary constructor from which you call the primary constructor in which you'll declare the properties you want to see in the toString() like this :

```
import kotlin.properties.Delegates
import kotlin.collections.MutableList

const val DEVICE_MODE_MANUAL = 10
const val DEVICE_MODE_AUTO = 20
const val DEVICE_MODE_OVERRIDE = 30

data class Device private constructor ( val name: String, val id: Int, val mode: Int, val strength: Int ) {   

    constructor( deviceModel: DeviceModel, deviceStatus: DeviceStatusModel  ) : 
    this(
        name = deviceModel.name ?: "Unknown",
        id = deviceModel.id ?: -1,
        mode = when(deviceStatus.mode) {
            1 -> DEVICE_MODE_MANUAL
            2 -> DEVICE_MODE_AUTO
            3 -> DEVICE_MODE_OVERRIDE
            else -> DEVICE_MODE_MANUAL
        },
        strength = deviceStatus.strength ?: 0
    ) 
}

data class DeviceModel( val name: String, val id: Int )

data class DeviceStatusModel( val mode: Int, val strength: Int )

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val deviceModel = DeviceModel( "Test ", 35 )
    val deviceStatusModel = DeviceStatusModel( 1, 42 )
    val device = Device( deviceModel, deviceStatusModel )
    println( device )
}
```

**NB** : I supposed you didn't want people to instantiate your object in other way than through the DeviceModel and DeviceStatusModel so i made the primary constructor private

Comment: Thanks, this is a clever solution that allows keeping a simple constructor for callers while leveraging the default toString.

Answer (score 6):

You can override the `toString()` method and provide any implementation that you need, instead of the default compiler-generated implementation.

Comment: Yes, that's clearly an option, but I wanted to know if there's a way to tell the compiler which properties to take into account for the auto generated methods, having to override them sort of defeats the purpose of a data class. I guess I'll have to change the constructor and do the logic on the caller side if there's no other way.

Comment: There is a way to tell the compiler: by writing code in the toString() method. We do not want to come up with an alternative mini-language for describing how toString() and equals() should work when we already have a perfectly fine general-purpose language for this task.

Comment: @Francesc First sentence in https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html is *We frequently create a class to do nothing but hold data*. Data class have a single purpose to store data, so only taking constructor properties into account doesn't really defeat the purpose. And if you need some logic when constructing an instance, rather use a Factory or a builder which is more flexible